# how can I prove that 29341 is not a prime number, with Fermat

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fermat-numbers

I know that the formula is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiF11.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: In what sense is that a formula?  What's a cousin?

Comment: Can you improve your question?  As it stands, it is not at all clear what you are asking.  $29341$ is a [Carmichael Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number)...does that have anything to do with what you are asking?

Comment: @lulu: Google translator writes "cousin"  from Spanish "primo" because  "primo" is a homonym in Spanish: it is either a  prime number and a son of an uncle.

Comment: @Piquito  Oh, thanks!  Never knew that.  Worth remarking that there is a notion of "cousin primes"  (primes which differ by $4$).  Maybe worth running that through google translate.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Comment: I subscribe voting to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Hint:

You can use Fermats Little Theorem. Which says
$$
a^{p-1}\equiv \cases{1 \ \ (\bmod p) \ \ if \ \ p\nmid a\\ 0 \ \ (\bmod p) \ \ if \ \ p\mid a}
$$
where $p$ is a prime and $a$ is any integer.

Hope this helps and this is what you meant.

Comment: Or just observe that $29,341=793\cdot 37$.